# Could not load file or assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=5.6.0.0 after upgrading Azure Function's nuget packages to 3.0.4 or 3.0.5

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

We have had an Azure Function V3 that has a reference to another C# project in a VS 2019 solution. There are some extension methods in the other C# project using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt Version=5.6.0.0 assembly to perform token validation. The Azure Function has been working fine by using those extension methods to validate token. The following code snippet shows the nuget packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService" Version="1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid" Version="3.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.3" />
```

We upgraded the nuget packages in the azure function according to the following list and started receiving the exception reflected the title of this ticket. What's the solution or workaround to solve this problem?

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SignalRService" Version="1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid" Version="3.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventGrid" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="1.1.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.4" />
```

We also tried Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions version 3.0.5 but it exhibits the same problem What is the solution for this problem? Is this an issue to be fixed in the upgraded nuget package?

Comment: take a look at the packages in your Visual Studio. I believe there are some compatibility issues and some package may not be installed properly (or some downgrade issue). PS: skip Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 3.0.4

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio that's not the case.

Comment: if you use 3.0.3 does it work properly?

Comment: 3.0.3 works well but we'd rather keep upgrading when a new version of the package is released.

Comment: raise an issue on github. 3.0.4 had broken the DI part which was fixed on 3.0.5, but according to your issue, it may had affected other parts too. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues

Comment: Already opened an issues.